# T-SQL SYNTAX ISSUE - using OR in CASE statement

Tags: t-sql, syntax, case

i would like to build a CASE statement that incorporates the following logic, but the sql compiler does not like the 'OR' in my statement:

```
CASE expression
WHEN expression1 OR expression2
THEN <yadda yadda>
ELSE <yadda yadda>
END
```

**more specific code below:**

```
CASE @var1
WHEN '99' OR '22'   
            THEN        
                (CASE @var2
                WHEN 'All' THEN col1
                ELSE @var2
                END)
END
```

Comment: This is allowed. You probably have an error in one of your exact expressions. Please post them.

Comment: Following `CASE expression` it is not allowed to have `OR`. There are two forms of the grammar. That is the simple form. You need the [searched form](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Variable INT;
SET @Variable = 1;

SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN @Variable = 1 OR @Variable = 2 THEN 'It is 1 or 2'
        WHEN @Variable = 3 THEN 'It is 3'
        ELSE 'It is not 1, 2, or 3'
    END AS [SomeField]
```

MSDN docs for [CASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql), [OR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/or-transact-sql), and [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/expressions-transact-sql).

Answer (score 6):

Based on your edits, you don't even need an `OR` statement:

```
CASE 
    WHEN @var1 IN ('99', '22')                
    THEN                         
         (CASE @var2                 
          WHEN 'All' 
          THEN col1                 
          ELSE @var2                 
          END) 
    END
```