# SQL OR within WHEN (in CASE)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Strangely i could not find this on the web,
I need an OR within a when clause in a case statement, something like:

```
SELECT type,color,brand,CASE type WHEN "foo" OR "BAR" OR "somethingelse" THEN SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE .... > ....;
```

I just cant find a way to make it work, i have tried enclosing it in parenthesys:

```
SELECT type,color,brand,CASE type WHEN ("foo" OR "BAR" OR "somethingelse") THEN SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE .... > ....;
```

Or in square brackets:

```
SELECT type,color,brand,CASE type WHEN ["foo" OR "BAR" OR "somethingelse"] THEN SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE .... > ....;
```

The problem is that i have more groups of options to check, and make a single WHEN for each of them, will make my query super long.
Nothing, any advice?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697127/t-sql-syntax-issue-using-or-in-case-statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`case` has two forms  Only one can use `Or`

1. `case x when val1 then result1 when val2 then result2 else defaultResult end`
2. `case when x = val1 then result1 When y = val2 then result2 Else DefaultResult end`, 
       or, more generally:
      `case when [boolExp1] then reslt1 when [boolExp2] then reslt2 else defltReslt end`

the second form can use `Or`, or any other Boolean operator for that matter (except `Exists` as I recall)

```
 case when x = val1 or y = val2 or z in (val3, val4, val5) then result1 
      else defaultResult end
```

Comment: Thx Charles, this has solved my issue, going to solve in a minute :) thx!

Answer (score 1):

In `CASE` you cannot start a separate SELECT without brackets ... and the `OR` is possible with the following:

```
CASE WHEN type IN ("foo","BAR","somethingelse") THEN ... ELSE END
```

If you want to get the target value from a `select` call (subquery) then do this in the `THEN` section

```
... THEN ( SELECT col1 FROM tble WHERE ... ) ELSE END
```

Comment: Hi cars10, thats exactly what i have, i will edit my post, this is just a quick sample query that i wrote to explain my problem.